# Compile NSLog with unsigned int and unsigned long on iOS and OSX without a warning

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

On iOS `NSUInteger` is a `unsigned int`, on OSX it is a `unsigned long`. How can I make a print statement like

```
 NSLog(@"Array has %d elements.",[array count]);
```

compile on both platforms without a warning? I can of course use an `#ifdef #else #endif` construct but that will add 4 lines of code. I could also cast the return value to unsigned int. Is there a shorter solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about a cast up to the larger of the two?

```
NSLog(@"Array has %ld elements.",(unsigned long)[array count]);
```

No warning in iOS, and I think it's a no-op in OSX.

Comment: The best way is `NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)array.count);` for `NSUInteger`, and `NSLog(@"%ld", (long)button.tag);` for `NSInteger`: no warnings in either 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

How about a cast up to the larger of the two?

```
NSLog(@"Array has %ld elements.",(unsigned long)[array count]);
No warning in iOS, and I think it's a no-op in OSX.
```