# unsigned int and unsigned long Xcode warnings in NSLogs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslog, unsigned-integer

This is more of an annoyance than anything. Has anyone else run across this?

For debugging purposes, I'm spitting out the count of the `_fetchedResults`. Xcode gives me an `unsigned int` warning when I use `%u`, and then offers to change it to `%lu`.

[image]

OK Xcode, sure, go right ahead.

Then it immediately barks at me again with an `unsigned long` warning and offers to change it *back* `%lu` to a `%u`. And the cycle repeats. Of course, I can just delete the `NSLog`, but I'm using it during testing.  And frankly it's more annoying than anything else.

[image]

Anyone else run across this before?  Not sure how much it matters, but I'm on Xcode 7.3 with a deployment target of 9.0.x.

Comment: Sometimes for debug purposes, I use `%@` and `@(myIntLongOrWhatverPrimitiveNum)` because XCode may throws warning in case of 64bits/32bits devices.

Comment: I won't add another answer because they explained the solution, however, I would really advice to just use `%@` and `@(myInt)`. It's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this SO thread:
[Compile NSLog with unsigned int and unsigned long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349844/compile-nslog-with-unsigned-int-and-unsigned-long-on-ios-and-osx-without-a-warni?rq=1)

It says-

```
NSLog(@"Array has %ld elements.",(unsigned long)[array count]);
```

And also says-

> The best way is `NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)array.count);` for NSUInteger,
>   and `NSLog(@"%ld", (long)button.tag);` for NSInteger: no warnings in either 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: Sweet Thanks to you both DashAndRest and user3182143 ... fastest answer I've ever received on Stack.  Have a great weekend.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSLog(@"row: %lu", (unsigned long)[_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]);
```

Description

> a 32-bit unsigned integer on 32-bit platforms
>
> 64-bit unsigned integer on 64-bit platforms.

```
Type       Format Specifier    Cast
----       ----------------    ----
NSInteger    %ld               long
NSUInteger   %lu               unsigned long
```